# Gulp and Angular: (Error) The controller with the name is not registered

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, single-page-application

I have a SPA based AngularJS which contains several components as follow:

```
app
  |_components
    |_home
      |_home.component.js
      |_home.html
  ...
  |_app.js
  |_app.config.js
  |_app.module.js
  |_app.routes.js
  |_app.run.js
index.html
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp').controller('appCtrl', AppController);

    function AppController() {
        // code here
    }
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
        <!-- inject:css -->
        <!-- endinject -->
        <!-- inject:js -->
        <!-- endinject -->
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl as vm" ng-strict-di>
        <app-home></app-home>
        <!-- ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

**home.component.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp').component('appHome', {
        templateUrl: 'components/home/home.html',
        controller: HomeCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindings: {}
    });

    function HomeCtrl() {
        // code here
    }
})();
```

**home.html**

```
<div>
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
</div>
```

With usage of Gulp all scripts will be packed into single js file (libraries into another js file) and then it will be injected into index.html. The script will be packed in the following order: app.module.js, app.js, app.routes.js, app.config.js, app.run.js
Running of the app throws following errors in browser console:

```
Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'appCtrl' is not registered.
```

and

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: components/home/home.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
```

I checked my codes several times (typo etc.) but I could not find where exactly I am doing wrong. So, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is appController? Where is it defined? Where is it used? The error complains about appController. The index.html uses appCtrl.

Comment: @JB Nizet, sorry my bad, it was only typo. I have updated the error message